# I got the table in right place but the word "Example" become right below the table. How can I fix example above table?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\begin{table}[H]%!t or htbp or htb
\label{full_adder_example}
\centering
\caption{Base sequences from Turyn sequences}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
TrS of lengths & BS of lengths  \\
 m+1,m+1,m,m & 2m+2, 2m+2, 2m+1, 2m+1 \\
\hline
11-1-1 ; 11-11 & 11111-11-1 ; -11111-11-1\\
 111; 1-11& 111-1-111 ; 1-111-1-11 \\
\hline
11-111 ; 1111-1 & 11111-1-11-11 ; -11111-1-11-11 \\
11-1-1 : 1-11-1 & 111-1111-1-1 ; 1-1111-111-1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Use `\begin{example}
\mbox{}\par
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
...\end{table}` (I assume you loaded the `float` package).

Comment: Also, always use `\label` **after** `\caption` in floats!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a `table` here: that is a floating environment and you don't want it to float.  Instead use a `center` environment and add a caption via the `capt-of` or `caption` package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \leavevmode
  \begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Base sequences from Turyn sequences}
    \label{full_adder_example}
    \smallskip
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule
      TrS of lengths & BS of lengths  \\
      \( m+1, m+1 ,m,m\) & \(2m+2, 2m+2, 2m+1, 2m+1\) \\
      \midrule
      11-1-1 ; 11-11 & 11111-11-1 ; -11111-11-1\\
      111; 1-11& 111-1-111 ; 1-111-1-11 \\
      \midrule
      11-111 ; 1111-1 & 11111-1-11-11 ; -11111-1-11-11 \\
      11-1-1 : 1-11-1 & 111-1111-1-1 ; 1-1111-111-1\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Other changes made:

- placing `center` at the beginning of the `example` environment often needs `\leavevmode` escape
- `\label` has to appear after the `\caption` command, otherwise you get a wrong number
- tables are best without vertical lines, see the [`booktabs` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs); that package has been used to add rules of varying thickness
- mathematics should be written as such: either in `\(...\)` or in `$...$`